# How to view permissions, roles associated with my user account in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

Earlier it seemed trivial, but not able to find all permissions/roles of my user account in GCP:
either thru console
or thru gcloud command

Could find the details for projects I am part of, but not of my user.

Comment: Didn't get you. can't you see your identity on `https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=[PROJECT_ID]` ? note: your identity could be member of a group. You need to check what's on the IAM page

Comment: What do you mean **but not able to find**? What have you tried? Edit your question with details and context.

Comment: @AtefHares : I want to see permsisions and roles assigned to my user account , NOT the project.

Comment: IAM Roles are not assigned to your user account. Roles are assigned to resources with your identity as a member. The project is one type of resource.

Comment: @JohnHanley : In "Google Cloud Platform for Architects" book, I read "permissions are assigned to roles, and users and then assigned to roles as well".

Comment: When you assign a role to a resource, it's named a policy. Then you can bind that policy with one or several account (user account or service account); it's named a policy binding. That's why you can see in gcloud "add-iam-policy-binding" on different types of resources

Comment: I would need to see the context of the book you reference, but at this point the text you copied from the book is incorrect. Google Cloud IAM is primarily **resource** based. There is no API that takes only your user identity and returns a permissions list. You must query the resource(s) to determine who has been granted which roles. Review this command to query the **project** resource: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/get-iam-policy

Comment: Note: There are other resources that have IAM policies as well. The project is just one resource that accepts a *policy** binding.